# When did the word "intercourse" become sexual?

Tags: meaning

When reading books written in the 1800's, the word intercourse is used without any sexual connotation. Example: during our intercourse with others. It is similar to relationship or dealings.

Comment: 1789. At least, that is what [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=intercourse&searchmode=none) says. So for texts from the 1800's you might want to be very careful about the context. :)

Comment: the word is **currently** used to mean simply talking or dealings. that's the current first dictionary definition. it can **also** be used to mean "sexual activity".

Comment: That's just one usage of "intercourse".  There's *social intercourse, spiritual intercourse, inventive intercourse*, for starters.  All from a quick search of Google Books.